# FormBuilder - Use ChoiceView instead with ChoiceType

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I'm trying to set `disabled`on a placeholder of a `ChoiceType`.

While I found some answers here on SO, I wasn't able to apply them.
Meanwhile, I've noticed something, and would need it to do it.

As it stand, when we dump `choices` in the twig view, we can notice that `choices` is an array made of several `ChoiceView`.

Thus, I thought, maybe, I could use `ChoiceView` directly in the formBuilder, like this:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder->add('title')
            ->add('desc')
            ->add('status', ChoiceType::class, array(
                'choices'=>array(
                    new ChoiceView('', '', 'Select a status, array('disabled'=>'disabled')),
                    'Draft'=>'draft',
                    'Complete'=>'complete',
                    'Aborted'=>'aborted',
                ),
            ));
}
```

But as excepted, it doesn't works...

Does anyone know a way to build your form while using `ChoiceView`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to manipulate `FormView` objects, you have to implement the `finishView` method on your FormType.

In your specific case :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add(
        'status',
        ChoiceType::class,
        array(
            'choices' => array(
                'Draft' => 'draft',
                'Complete' => 'complete',
                'Aborted' => 'aborted',
            ),
        )
    );
}

public function finishView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
{
    array_unshift(
        $view->children['status']->vars['choices'],
        new ChoiceView('', '', 'Select a status', array('disabled' => 'disabled'))
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... I knew I was close, but wasn't aware of `finishView()` function... Will bookmark this answer, will prove useful... :)